# How to create a sprite for cube

Tags: adobe-photoshop, sprite, image-sprite

I created a cube using Hexels and imported it into Photoshop. The challenge I am having is how to create a running sprite with it.

I tried using Spriter Pro but noticed no pivot point that would help me make it rotate in the direction as seen in [pic](http://snag.gy/aZPEb.jpg)

Any help with tools that could generate the frames would be much appreciated.

Comment: If I understand correctly you made a 2D representation of a cube and are trying to rotate it in 3D space. That doesn't really work.

Comment: Hi @Ryan all I am trying to achieve is something similar to this [video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qvb6vw8knlznsaq/ice_video_20160216-145300.webm?dl=0)

Comment: RE "pic" :: *"This webpage is not available"*

Comment: Forgive me if I'm wrong. I've never used or even heard of Hexel before but from what I see its a 2D program. There's not going to be any easy way to make that animation out of an incomplete "cube". I say "cube" with quotes because that's the thing... its not a cube. It's 3 planes skewed to look like it *might be* a cube. It could be hollow, it could be round on the back, it could be missing a side, it could stick out to a point... we and the computer have no idea because right now its just 3 planes. Unless I'm not understanding Hexel and it is a 3D application but doesnt appear to be

Comment: @SOIA the page is there - Its a video link https://goo.gl/iG4TpI